# Invoke-Command doesn't return objects based on PSObject properties

Tags: powershell

Working with the script below whose job it is to reach out to remote machines and pulls the membership of the local group and then create custom PS objects to sort the data as I need. The code works fine when pulling from the local machine and the PSCustomObject is honored. However, on a remote call, the objects do not get stored properly in the PScustomObjects.

Looking for some insight/help to return these in the proper format

```
$params = $args
$Target = $args[0]
$PrivUser = "$($params[1])\$($params[2])"
$PrivPwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $params[3] -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = [pscredential]::new($PrivUser,$PrivPwd)
$Groups =  @('Administrators','Remote Desktop Users','Power Users')
$results = @()
try {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Target -Credential $cred -HideComputerName -ScriptBlock {
          #Change $using:groups to $groups to pull local objects
        foreach($group in $using:Groups) 
        {
        foreach($member in Get-LocalGroupMember -Name $group) {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                Machine     = $env:COMPUTERNAME
                Group       = $group
                Member      = $member.Name
            }
        }
            $results += $output
        }
        return $results 
        
    }
 

} catch {
    throw "Unable to connect to target: $($args[0]) `n$_"
}
```

Output from local machine

```
Machine Group                Member               
------- -----                ------               
BLT-SRV Administrators       BLT\Domain Admins    
BLT-SRV Administrators       BLT\svr.blt.ad.ss    
BLT-SRV Administrators       BLT\svr.blt.ss.ps    
BLT-SRV Administrators       BLT\svr.kiwi         
BLT-SRV Administrators       BLT-SRV\Administrator
BLT-SRV Administrators       BLT-SRV\BLT_Admin    
BLT-SRV Remote Desktop Users BLT\cpopopo
```

Output from remote machine

```
Machine    : BLT-SRV
Group      : Administrators
Member     : BLT\Domain Admins
RunspaceId : 81840b66-4a15-467f-956f-1552b068847d

Machine    : BLT-SRV
Group      : Administrators
Member     : BLT\svr.blt.ad.ss
RunspaceId : 81840b66-4a15-467f-956f-1552b068847d

Machine    : BLT-SRV
Group      : Administrators
Member     : BLT\svr.blt.ss.ps
RunspaceId : 81840b66-4a15-467f-956f-1552b068847d

Machine    : BLT-SRV
Group      : Administrators
Member     : BLT\svr.kiwi
RunspaceId : 81840b66-4a15-467f-956f-1552b068847d

Machine    : BLT-SRV
Group      : Administrators
Member     : BLT-SRV\Administrator
RunspaceId : 81840b66-4a15-467f-956f-1552b068847d

Machine    : BLT-SRV
Group      : Administrators
Member     : BLT-SRV\BLT_Admin
RunspaceId : 81840b66-4a15-467f-956f-1552b068847d

Machine    : BLT-SRV
Group      : Remote Desktop Users
Member     : BLT\hgdghdh
RunspaceId : 81840b66-4a15-467f-956f-1552b068847d
```

Comment: Is the objects being displayed as list instead of as a table the issue? Or what is the issue

Comment: As a list when it should be in a table

Comment: Is that a result of the remote connection? I didn't have to format it to a table when running the same code directly against a machine.

Not sure exactly how to tell it to do a table inline

Comment: how exactly would i edit this inline to restrict that output. Sorry newbie here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excluding the `RunspaceId` property should, by default, display the object as a Table:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Target -Credential $cred -HideComputerName -ScriptBlock {
    foreach($group in $using:Groups) {
        foreach($member in Get-LocalGroupMember -Name $group) {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                Machine     = $env:COMPUTERNAME
                Group       = $group
                Member      = $member.Name
            }
        }
    }
} | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty RunspaceId
```

Alternatively, you can pipe the result of `Invoke-Command` to `Format-Table` to force the object to be displayed as table:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Target -Credential $cred -HideComputerName -ScriptBlock {
    # code here
} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

However, **do note**, [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-7.2) is meant **exclusively for console display**, do not use it if you want to export the output.

Answer (score 0):

You're running up against serialization.
See [this post to understand](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/how-objects-are-sent-to-and-from-remote-sessions/) what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for the article. By chance any other input you could give on a solution?

Comment: Query: Powershell deserialize

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your problem, but I think you're getting the same result, but it's being shown differently. You can force table view (your first output example) using `Format-Table` (or simply `ft`). To get a list view (the second one), use `Format-List` (or `fl`). Both commands below return the same result, but shows it in a different way:

`Get-ChildItem -Path c:\ | Format-Table`

`Get-ChildItem -Path c:\ | Format-List`